# ASP.NET MVC Shared Layout Fields keep values to use in all views

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter

I have two fields in my Shared/~Layout that my user can use to filter information in my entire WebSite. Basically it loads the partial before the @RenderBody, however this partial always is reloaded when the user is redirected to another view, and the values that were selected are lost.

@Html.Partial("_FiltrosTop")

@RenderBody()

I would like to know, if there is a way to keep the values that were selected. I'm using C#, MVC4, ASP.NET, Jquery and KnockoutJS.
To load the fields data, I'm currently using Ajax and Jquery.

Comment: My suggestion is make _FiltrosTop be the html rendered in RenderBody(). Add a container div at the bottom of your _FiltrosTop view and just do ajax gets to get html, then empty and append the new html into the container div. If you are going to deal with a lot of views this is going to be very hectic. If its just a couple this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem using Jquery-cookie.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Thanks all.